# How to construct a convergent sequence of pre-images of a convergent sequence?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

This question is motivated by a theorem that has been widely discussed in this site:

> **Proposition 1.** Given $X$ and $Y$ topological spaces, with $X$ a first-countable space, if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and the sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converges to a limit $x$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

An interesting converse of that question would be:

> If $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are differentiable manifolds of the same dimention, then given a proper, surjective and differentiable map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a convergent sequence  $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then there exist a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ so that $f(x_n) = y_n$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

At least for real-valued function, i.e., for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the question seems to have a positive answer. The reason for it is that proper and subjective maps explodes in both directions, but I couldn't find an actual proof.

P.S.: If needed for an easy proof, it might be assumed that the derivative has full rank in an open and dense set of $X$, but you can drop this assumption anytime you want.

> **Bounty question.:** If $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are differentiable manifolds of the same dimention, then given a proper, surjective and differentiable map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ so that $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected. Then, for any convergent sequence  $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, there exist a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ so that $f(x_n) = y_n$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Without properness I had an immediate counterexample.  If you don’t have any rank conditions on the derivative, is differentiability getting you anything? Do you have a continuous counterexample?

Comment: No I haven't any counterexample. Your continuous example posted here would be enlightening.

Comment: I have some rank conditions on derivative. The rank of the derivative is full in an open and dense set. =) Do you want I add this constraint in the question?

Here, the function being differentiable is just to avoid some weird counterexamples.

Comment: I don't have a *proper* counterexample, either continuous or smooth. My obvious counterexample failed to be proper. What goes wrong with just using continuity and taking the preimage of the compact set $\{y_n,y\}$?

Comment: My main concern here is to prove that at least one choice of sequence of elements in  pre-image by $\{y^{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ will actually converge to the limit $\lim y^{k}$, say $y$. I don't know how to guarantee that. Does sequence of real numbers $\{\text{dist} (f^{-1}(\{y^{k}\}), f^{-1}(\{y\}))\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to zero?

Comment: If a subsequence will do, that's easy. :)

Comment: Note that I don't want a converging subsequence, but the convergence of the full sequence of pre-images.

Comment: Here is an example of the failure of Theorem 1 when manifolds are allowed to have nonempty boundary: Take the obvious map $(-\infty,0]\sqcup[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and consider the sequence $\{(-1)^n/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: What is that obvious map?

Comment: The map which is the identity on each summand of the disjoint union.

Comment: Can you define it explicity? Because I'm thinking about the identity on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$. You function does not map onto the real line, i.e., is not surjective.

Comment: The intervals are half closed. That is $[0,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\geq0\}$ and $(-\infty,0]=\{x\in X\mid x\leq 0\}$. The domain is the disjoint union $(-\infty,0]\sqcup[0,\infty)$ and the mapping onto $\mathbb{R}$ takes $x$ to $x$. It is closed and one-to-one away from the origin. It is two-to-one at the origin. The sequence under consideration oscillates around $0$ and converges to $0$. The sequence lifts (uniquely) to $(-\infty,0]\sqcup[0,\infty)$, but not as a convergent sequence.

Comment: The domain $(-\infty,0]\sqcup[0,\infty)$ is a smooth manifold with boundary. You can produce a similar example with a connected domain by taking the map $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow S^1$ given by $f(t)=\exp(\pi it)$.

Comment: Please, provide a complete answer and how that manifold is constructed. I am not too familiar with Geometry. If It is right, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here is an example to show that the theorem cannot hold for smooth, proper surjections between manifolds with nonempty boundary. At the very least the example shows that the theorem fails for continuous maps between locally connected, locally compact, separable metric spaces.

Let
$$X=\{(x,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\geq0\}\cup\{(y,-1)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y\leq 0\}$$
carry the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x,t)=x.$$
Then $f$ is proper and surjective. That is, $f$ is continuous and closed, and $f^{-1}(x)$ is compact for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In fact $f^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton whenever $x\neq 0$, while $|f^{-1}(0)|=2$.

Now consider the sequence $\{y_n=(-1)^n/n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, which converges to $0$. Letting $x_n=((-1)^n/n,(-1)^n)$ we obtain a sequence $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in $X$ satisfying $f(x_n)=y_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Of course $x_n$ is the unique point of $X$ with $f(x_n)=y_n$. The sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\{x_n\}$ does not converge in $X$. Since there is no other choice for the sequence $\{x_n\}$, we see that Theorem 1 fails for the spaces and maps in the present example.

*Remark 1*: The example above can be altered so that both target and domain are compact and connected: simply take $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow S^1$ given by $f(x)=\exp(\pi it)$. $\quad\square$

*Remark 2*: If we consider maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ which are proper and monotone (ie $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact and *connected* for each $y\in Y$), then it seems likely that the theorem should be true. $\quad\square$

Here is a positive result.

> *Lemma*: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between Hausdorff spaces $X,Y$. Assume that  $X$ is first-countable and that $f$ is an open surjection. Then for any $y\in Y$, any $x\in f^{-1}(y)$, and any sequence $\{y_n\}_\mathbb{N}\subseteq Y$ converging to $y$, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_\mathbb{N}\subseteq X$ which converges to $x$ and satisfies $f(x_n)=y_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof**: Given $y_n\rightarrow y$ and $x\in f^{-1}(y)$, we will produce the sequence $\{x_n\}_\mathbb{N}$. Begin by fixing a neighourhood base $\{U_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ for $x$ consisting of a sequence of decreasing open subsets of $X$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ write $V_n=f(U_n)$. Since $f$ is open and surjective, $\{V_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ is a neighbourhood base for $y=f(x)$ (note that $Y$ is necessarily first-countable).

Now, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $N(k)$ such that $y_n\in V_k$ whenever $n\geq N(k)$. Fixing an $N(k)$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we can, without loss of generality, assume that $1<N(k)<N(k+1)$.

Now choose $x_n\in X$ as follows. If $n<N(1)$, then take any $x_n\in f^{-1}(y_n)$. If $N(k)\leq n<N(k+1)$ pick any $x_n\in f^{-1}(x_n)\cap U_k$.

The resulting sequence $\{x_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ lifts $\{y_n\}_\mathbb{N}$, so we'll be done if we can show that it converges to $x$. To this end suppose $W\subseteq X$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $x\in U_k\subseteq W$. Since $y_n\in V_k$ whenever $n\geq N(k)$, we have $x_n\in U_k\subseteq W$ whenever $n\geq N(K)$. This shows that $x_n\rightarrow x$. $\quad\square$

Now this can be put to use as follows. Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a $C^1$-map between manifolds $X,Y$. The implicit function theorem implies that $f$ is open on $X\setminus D$, where $D=\{x\in X\mid rank(df)<\dim X\}$

> Assume that $\dim Y>1$ and that $\{x\in X\mid rank(fd),\dim X\}$ consists of isolated points. Then $f$ is open.

The details of this are contained in the paper *On Open Maps*, Amer. Math. Monthly, **96** (1989), 242-243, which is authored by J. Crowe and D. Samperi.

The point is that any open map has the required sequence lifting property. There just happen to be an abundance of open maps when we impose a few conditions. Feel free to let me know if every proper $C^1$ map you would like to consider meets these conditions.

Comment: My question is about the existence of a convergent sequence $(x^{k})$ so that $f(x_n) = y_n$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$; not about the existance of a divergent sequence. You construct an wrong example. Your positive last result is quite interesting, btw! I think you deverve more than just an one like.

Comment: I was supplying a counterexample, not an example. You asked for it above. I'm afraid I don't know much about smooth maps, so past what I wrote, you'll have to figure out how much mileage you can get out of it.

Comment: Maybe you missed the point of the example. The lift of the sequence $y_n$ is *unique*, and this unique sequence does not converge. Therefore no convergent lift exists..

Comment: There exists **no convergent sequence** in the example I have given.

Comment: That's true! I missed that point.

Comment: I was just thinking that you can replace $X$ with $X'=X\cup \{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid -1\leq y\leq 1\}$ and take the map $f':X'\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f'|_X=f$ and $f'(0,t)=0$. The space $X'$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is proper and piecewise smooth.

Comment: My open maps do not meet these conditions of being open subjection. My maps have a set of curves in which it is not full rank. Specifically, my map is the one displayed in (2.III.b) in the article "Real analytic desingularization and subanalytic sets: an elementary approach". In my context, I have used the Theorem 2.1. to characterize a sequential property of constrained optimization problems. The good part is that my map satisfies your Remark 2 conditions. =)

Comment: Your counterexample helped me find the error in my proof and why in my case it's right. My manifold  is, locally, diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Your variety does not. That's the reason things work for me. I will add a positive answer as soon as I end my proof here. I'm quite occupied now.

Comment: R.W, I'm glad to hear that my ideas were useful to you. I'll check back later in the week and see if you've had the time to add anything.

Comment: I encountered some problems in my proof. I implicitly assumed that all functions $g(x)= \text{dist} (f^{-1} (x), z)$ are contínuous, but this is equivalent to my statement in my setting.